Seamless m4t T2TT finetuning
Is there a way to finetune the Seamless-m4t-large model for Text-to-Text task, as the official git repo "facebookresearch/seamless_communication" doesn't support the same currently?
Worked on modifying the repo code for the same but did not find any leads.
